# Showing $\int _{0} ^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos^{2022}(x)}{\sin^{2022}(x) + \cos^{2022}(x) } dx \approx \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Show that $$\int_{0} ^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos^{2022}(x)}{\sin^{2022}(x) + \cos^{2022}(x) } dx \approx \frac{\pi}{4}$$

My method was this: I tried using $x \to \pi/4-x$ conversion but that doesn't lead to common denominator. Next thing I tried was to take help of approximation as the answer too is an approximation, so I thought as $\cos x >\sin x$ in $(0,\pi/4)$, but didn't got a good reason to neglect the $\sin^{2022}(x)$ in comparison to $\cos^{2022}x$. Can anyone explain how we can do so?

Note: also I think at $x= \pi/4$ we cannot neglect at all since both would be equal, so what in that point, will the integral be not a bit more then?

Comment: Integration Bee 2022.

Comment: Yeah i saw in a recent video of a integration bee in youtube so thought of asking after i tried this

Comment: Arnold Ross used to ask, "What is an approximation to five?" and his answer was, "Any number except five." So all you have to do is to prove that the integral isn't exactly $\pi/4$.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer: Even though it looks symbolically very different, I hope you will see your ideas reflected in my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start with
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos^{2022}x}{\sin^{2022}x+\cos^{2022}x} \,dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac1{\tan^{2022}x+1} \,dx = \int_0^1 \frac1{u^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du
$$
after setting $u=\tan x$. Since $\dfrac1{u^{2022}+1}<1$ for $x\in(0,1)$, this is clearly less than $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac1{u^2+1}\,du = \frac\pi4$. On the other hand, for any $c\in(0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac1{u^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du &= \int_0^c \frac1{u^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du + \int_c^1 \frac1{u^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du \\
&> \int_0^c \frac1{c^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du + \int_c^1 \frac1{1^{2022}+1} \frac1{u^2+1} \,du \\
&= \frac1{c^{2022}+1} \arctan c + \frac12 \biggl( \frac\pi4 - \arctan c \biggr),
\end{align*}
which can be analyzed either analytically or numerically. For example, taking $c=0.99568$ in this lower bound yields an approximation no worse than $0.784192$, as compared with $\dfrac\pi4\approx 0.785398$ (and hence this approximation can be no worse than $0.16$% off).

This is an underappreciated technique in my opinion: after trying the most trivial bound possible (here, the integral is bounded above/below by the length of the interval of integration times the maximum/minimum of the integrand), split the object into two pieces and use the trivial bound on each piece separately.

Comment: I suppose that the $2002$ are in fact $2022$

Comment: Or you could just note that $\tan^{2022}x$ is negligible until just before $x=\pi/4$, so the integrand is basically $1$.

Comment: @J.G. Certainly that's the strategy (already suggested by the OP); this is one way of rigorously implementing that strategy.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry, can't spell :p

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$I_n := \int_{0} ^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos^n(x)}{\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x) } \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

We have
$$I_n = \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0} ^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin^n(x)}{\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x) } \,\mathrm{d} x .$$

Clearly, $I_n < \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 I_n &> \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0} ^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin^n(x)}{ \cos^n(x) } \,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &= \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0} ^{\pi/4} \tan^n x \,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &= \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0} ^{1} \frac{y^n}{1+y^2} \,\mathrm{d} y \\
 &\ge \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0} ^{1} y^n(1 - y^2/2) \,\mathrm{d} y\\
 &=  \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{n+5}{2(n+1)(n+3)}
\end{align*}
where we have used $\frac{1}{1+y^2} \le 1 - y^2/2$
for all $y\in [0, 1]$.

Thus, we have
$$\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{n+5}{2(n+1)(n+3)} < I_n < \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

**Question**: Can we obtain asymptotic expansion of $I_n$?

Comment: Really nice way , as for the question i think its possible though dont know how to

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer If you practice more, you will learn some skills/tricks.